# Difference between different lenght timestamp-indexed DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have two dataframes, both are indexed with timestamp values like '2021-03-23 13:04:00.134000+00:00'.

I would like to compute the difference between them on some columns, but the problem is that they are not time-aligned and have different number of rows.

Is there a good way to makes the difference of all the elements that have a time delta less then a specyfied amount and put NaN in the other cases?

Edit:

Dataframe 1:

```
|index| val1 | val 2 |
|--------------------------------| ---- | ---- |
|2021-03-23 13:04:00.134000+00:00| 200  | 50   |
|2021-03-23 13:34:00.134000+00:00| 100  | 10   |
|2021-03-23 14:04:00.134000+00:00| 100  | 10   |
```

Dataframe 2:

```
|index| val1 | val 2 |
|--------------------------------| ---- | ---- |
|2021-03-23 13:24:00.134000+00:00| 200  | 50   |
|2021-03-23 14:34:00.134000+00:00| 100  | 10   |
```

Expected output (difference between columns of Dataframe 1 and Dataframe 2) supposing that the time delta is 20 min:

```
|index| val1 | val 2 |
|--------------------------------| ---- | ---- |
|2021-03-23 13:04:00.134000+00:00| 0    | 0    |
|2021-03-23 13:44:00.134000+00:00| NaN  | NaN  |
|2021-03-23 15:04:00.134000+00:00| NaN  | NaN  |
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data - e.g. 5 rows for both DataFrames and also add expected ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) first:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                   df2, 
                   left_index=True, 
                   right_index=True,
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta('20Min'),
                   direction='forward',
                   suffixes=('','_'))
print (df)
                                  val1  val2  val1_  val2_
index                                                     
2021-03-23 13:04:00.134000+00:00   200    50  200.0   50.0
2021-03-23 13:34:00.134000+00:00   100    10    NaN    NaN
2021-03-23 14:04:00.134000+00:00   100    10    NaN    NaN
```

And then subtract columns which are same (difference only `_` added to end):

```
new = df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith('_')]
print (new)
Index(['val1_', 'val2_'], dtype='object')

orig = new.str.replace('_','')
print (orig)
Index(['val1', 'val2'], dtype='object')

df[orig] = df[orig].sub(df[new].to_numpy())

df = df.drop(new, axis=1)
print (df)
                                  val1  val2
index                                       
2021-03-23 13:04:00.134000+00:00   0.0   0.0
2021-03-23 13:34:00.134000+00:00   NaN   NaN
2021-03-23 14:04:00.134000+00:00   NaN   NaN
```